# Changing project path in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: project, aptana

Say I have my project in `c:\desktop\project_A` and I want to change the path of it to point at the `c:\desktop\project_B folder` instead. How do I do that without deleting the project from the list and creating a new one?

Answer (score 20):

You could achieve this in the current Studio 3:

1. Open Navigator view with **Window** > **Show View** > **Other** > **General** > **Navigator**;
2. Right-click on project_A in Navigator view and select **Move...**;
3. Modify the location to what project_B resides and click OK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Warning: if you move the project into a sub directory of the project itself Aptana will delete all the contents of the project.

Comment: Any idea why I get a "Problems encountered while moving resources. Resource already exists on disk: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project_A'. " ?? I'm just trying to move the project, not necessarily change the directory so I just made copy of project_A and called in project_B when trying this solution. Help! thanks