# Updating Document Root

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I've just started using Aptana now and think its a really good IDE for my use. I created a new project and started working with uploading files to the project. I changed the file system structure of my project and need to update the document root of the project however I can not find where I can do that. I went to the Project->Properties while I had my project highlighted and it did not have a place for me to edit the document root.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing project path in Aptana Studio 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801854/changing-project-path-in-aptana-studio-3)

Comment: That did not solve the issue.