# Aptana Studio 3: Export whole project settings

Tags: export, settings, aptana, workspace

I have installed Aptana Studio 3 on my PC at work, but now I want all settings at home too. My partitions are the same so I just have to import it. But how can I export the whole settings (with plugins, workspaces, formatter-settings, themes, etc.)?

Comment: Have you looked at what is available under File > Export?

Comment: Preferences, yes. But what about the whole program settings?

Answer (score 0):

On your work computer, navigate to your Aptana workspace folder (the folder that you specified as your workspace when you installed Aptana) and find a folder titled, `.metadata`. Save that folder to a thumb drive, Dropbox, etc.

When you get home, make sure Aptana is not running and go to the same folder, delete the current `.metadata` folder and replace it with the one you saved from earlier. (Warning: this will delete all current settings and project paths from your home computer).  Fire up Aptana and you should be good to go!

Note: Unless your project path's are exactly the same on your home and work computer, they will all come up as errors. It appears in order to correct this, unless there is functionality I'm not aware of, you will have to delete the project paths and recreate the paths on your new computer.  (Just to save you time, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801854/changing-project-path-in-aptana-studio-3) does not work for bad paths.)